# Content editor webpart not showing in Media and Content webpart forlder of SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online

Content editor is not showing in newly created SharePoint Online, till now I did following steps:

1. Enabled SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure in site collection features and SharePoint Server Publishing in Site features.
2. Enabled Custom Script from SharePoint admin
3. Also ran powershell online Set-SPOsite  -DenyAddAndCustomizePages 0

But still Content editor webpart is not showing in Media and Content webpart forlder of SharePoint Online, is it deprecated as mentioned in few articles.

Comment: Are you using modern communication site or team site?

Comment: Ganesh it is team  site

Answer (score 1):

Please go to site settings->site permissions->check permissions, check if the user deny with “Add and customize pages”.

[image]

If yes, it might cause we cannot view the Content Editor Web Part, to resolve this issue, please run the SharePoint Online Management Shell as administrator. And then run the following commands:

```
Connect-SPOService -Url https://tanent -admin.sharepoint.com/

Set-SPOSite -Identity https://<yourdomain>.sharepoint.com -DenyAddAndCustomizePages $false
```

Then check if you can view the Web Part.

Comment: Thank you Lisa for reply, I am getting your mentioned Deny thingy on subsite but not on root site